# Replace FCM (APNS) Push Notification on iOS devices

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently setting up push notifications for my app and I'm trying to replace old push notification that the user has received on their device (but yet not touched) with a newer one.

The push notification payload is pretty much identical, and so rather than the user having multiple notifications on their screen, I'm trying to replace the old one with a newer one.

This is possible and quite easy to achieve on Android by using the `tag` property (can be seen here in the FCM Go documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/messaging#AndroidNotification).

I've read the FCM documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) as well as posts on Medium (https://medium.com/the-guardian-mobile-innovation-lab/how-to-replace-the-content-of-an-ios-notification-2d8d93766446) which recommend adding a header value, `apns-collapse-id` but it doesn't work. The old notifications aren't replaced but rather just stacked.

Does anybody have experience with this working? I'm curious if I haven't somehow misconfigured it.

This is the Go code which I have so far. The constructed payloads are being sent to FCM and then sent to the device(s) via APNS.

```
var androidMessagingConfig = &messaging.AndroidConfig{
    Priority: "high",
    Notification: &messaging.AndroidNotification{
        ChannelID:   "fcm_default_channel",
        ClickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    },
}

var appleMessagingConfig = &messaging.APNSConfig{
    Headers: map[string]string{
        "apns-priority": "5",
    },
    Payload: &messaging.APNSPayload{
        Aps: &messaging.Aps{},
    },
}

notification := messaging.Notification{}
    switch source.Message.(type) {
    case *pb.Notification_AugmentedReality_:
        notification.Title = "Your AR is ready"
        notification.Body = "Go and check"
        androidMessagingConfig.Notification.Tag = "ar"
        appleMessagingConfig.Headers["apns-collapse-id"] = "ar"
        appleMessagingConfig.Headers["collapse_key"] = "ar"
        appleMessagingConfig.Payload.Aps.MutableContent = true
        appleMessagingConfig.Payload.Aps.ThreadID = "ar"
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown notification type")
    }
```